# What's the room number for Cuba Gooding jr?

Tags: pattern

Inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/whats-my-room-number), I have made this similar puzzle (the solution method is NOT identical)

In a hotel there are ten floors, with ten rooms at each floor. 
Currently 10 rooms are occupied.

- In room 13 Mr. Nelson is staying his last day.
- In room 21 Angela is hanging up a "Malerei" that has fallen down the wall.
- In room 23 Franz and Ferdinand have a principal meeting.
- In room 39 Joseph wins the day after Paul the Apostle has surrendered.
- In room 51 a King has a dream.
- In room 62 Zwedish football is born.
- In room 65 Pierce wants to travel the world and end in Europe for the second time.
- In room 82 Mr. Brown is serving NamNam for free.
- In room 88 Mrs. Carla is using a small and gentle computer for the first time.

**In what room would Cuba Gooding jr. want to stress down after the climax of a lifetime?**

Hint 1:

> This is a two-legged puzzle. The first leg is to find the one thing in common. That thing is layed out in a pattern. The pattern is leg two.

Hint 2:

> The first leg is relying heavily on association.

Hint 3:

> Mrs. Carla is working on formulating VALUEs important to here

Hint 4:

> First leg consists of one date pr. room.

Hint 5:

> Mrs. Carla is using Excel

---

---

---

### Chatroom:

To simplify our discussions, there now is a chat-room on this puzzle:
[chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21065/cuba-gooding-jr](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21065/cuba-gooding-jr)

---

---

---

Comment: I've moved all the comments here [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21065/cuba-gooding-jr). Comments should usually be used for clarification and questions to the author; extended discussion is much better served in chat. That being said, lots of information in that chatroom; definitely check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer:

> Room 47.

This is the reason:

> The date of the climax of the Cuba crisis was 28.october 1962. Formulated as a VALUE in Excel, would give 22947. Room number is identical to two last digits, based on the pattern of the other rooms.

Answer (score 3):

If you put the dates listed above into excel and then find their =VALUE all of their last two digits correspond to their room numbers.

CBJ's best known role is in Jerry McGuire, released 12/13/1996. That VALUE is 35412.

He is in room 12.

Comment: Almost there, but not yet. Your reasoning is correct, but the question is misinterpreted...

Answer (score 2):

Cuba would want to relax in Room 97.

Prepending a '19' in front of each room number gives a year that corresponds to the clue/event.  In the case of Cuba Gooding Jr, his climax was winning an Oscar in 1997 for his role in Jerry Maguire.

Comment: Not the right answer. But a star for being the first one to try an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the dates described:

Room 13:

> The date Nelson Mandela died

Room 21:

> The date of the fall of the Berlin Wall

Room 23:

> The date Gavrilo Princip assasinated Franz Ferdinand

Room 39:

> The date Stalingrad battle ended, the day after general Paulus surrendered to Joseph Stalin

Room 51:

> The date Martin Luther King jr. held his famous speech "I have a dream"

Room 62:

> The birth date of Zlatan Ibrahimovic

Room 65:

> The date of the second peace(Pierce) of world war in Europe

Room 82:

> The date of independence date for Vietnam

Room 88:

> The date of founding Microsoft

This would conclude leg one.
For leg two:

> Hints 3 and 5 combined with the limitation on room numbers given by floors and rooms pr. floor, would reveal the pattern.