# A batch of four sequence puzzles

Tags: number-sequence, letter-sequence

This is my fourth batch of sequence puzzles that are nasty and hard to solve; 
yet, each of them has a clear and justifiable solution.

---

> Sequence 1:
>   2, ?, ?, ?, 0, 3, 7, 6, 4, 6, 9, 0, ?, 0, 4, 3, 4, 9, 5, 7, 3, 7, 5, 4, 4, 9, 4, 3, ...

---

> Sequence 2:
>   Lt, Hd, Tu, Wk, ??, Gbb, Ak, M-kb

---

> Sequence 3:
>   ??, ??, ??, 2, 67, 62, 27, 14

---

> Sequence 4:
>   S, ?, ?, ?, B, F, B, R, A, R, V.

Comment: The prize goes to Len, since he solved the last and  thus hardest sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequence 2 is the list of:

> UN Secretary Generals - with their initials reversed
>  Trygve Lie, Dag Hammarskjöld, U Thant, Kurt Waldheim, Javier Pèrez de Cuèllar, Boutros Boutros-Ghali, Kofi Annan, Ban Ki-moon
>
>  So the full sequence is:
>  Lt, Hd, Tu, Wk, **Cdpj**, Gbb, Ak, M-kb

Comment: Oh, come on, this is getting ridiculous. +1 for digging that up though.

Comment: @dmg - Thanks, I agree. I think this [recent question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9657/a-list-of-eight-countries) was intended to be a clue ;-)

Comment: Good, this bugged me a long time. One more off from my list. (On a similar note: I have solved http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/whats-my-room-number because I noted the author's obsession with chemical puzzles).

Answer (score 4):

This time I could google sequence 3.

Sequence 3:

> Moon fact sheet: 
>  Metric Number of Moons:
>  0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 67, 62, 27, 14, 5
>  (so the three questionmarks are 0, 0, 1 for Mercury, Venus, Earth)

---

Added February 17. I think I have finally found the answer to sequence 4.

Sequence 4:

> summary, answers, questions, tags, badges, favorites, 
>  bounties, reputation, activities, responses, votes
>  The complete sequence is: **S, A, Q, T, B, F, B, R, A, R, V**.

Answer (score 3):

Sequence 1:

> To get each number in this sequence, add 1 to each digit of Pi(after the decimal point) and if it is 10, use 0(mod 10).

So, The full sequence is

> 2,5,2,6,0,3,7,6,4,6,9,0,8,0,4,3,4,9,5,7,3,7,4,3,3,9,4,3, ...

Comment: You will not get the "4,3,3,9,4,3, ..." at the end if you add one. You will get "5,4,4,9,4,3, ...". I'm gonna blame it on OP for now.

Comment: Interesting observation! I too think that the OP has made a mistake on that.

Comment: I was just a little bit too slow on this one.  Google found me a Spanish web page with part of this sequence, but I was not able to deduce the solution from it: http://matematicasaureas.blogia.com/

Comment: dmg is right. I had made a mistake. I have corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out!