# A list of eight countries

Tags: pattern, geography

Which country is missing on the following list?

> Norway, Sweden, Burma, Austria, Peru, ?????, Ghana, South Korea

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> **Egypt**

It is the list of home countries of UN Secretary Generals. And the only country missing from the list is

> **Egypt** (Boutros Boutros-Ghali)

Comment: Boutros Ghali was Prime Minister of Egypt, not UN Secretary General. That was his grandson, Boutros Boutros-Ghali.